# Display static image from iOS filesystem

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, react-native

I am currently trying to display a static image within my react native app. I am using the Image Component from React Native, so there is nothing custom.

Maybe important to mention is that i am opening the Main App with my Share Extension => Image Gallery, Select Image, Share with Main App.

On the Simulator it works just great, when i am using a real device nothing is displayed. Here is the Image path i am trying to display:

```
<Image
  style={styles.image}
  source={{
    uri: "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/156268E6-6BE0-4055-BF0E-0EDC546FC2F9/tmp/RNSE_TEMP_IMG.png",
    isStatic: true
  }}
/>
```

I have tried adding file:// + /private.... but this did not help at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: This may sound dumb but ... are you sure that image exists on your device?

Comment: well the image is in the image gallery and i am pretty sure its on the device too... not a dumb question at all ;)